# How to ask continuously for an input and sum the number entered by the client

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm asked to ask continuously if the user wants to continue adding the price of a product, and when the answer is no, i have to show the total price of all the products entered. Right now i have this, but it won't ask continuously, it just breaks after the first question and wouldn't ask for a second, third... times

```
price = 0
user = input ("Do you want to continue (yes/no):")
if user == "yes":
  for x in range(0,1):
    price = int( input("Please enter the price of the product" + str(x) + ":"))
    print(price)
elif user == "no":
  print("Your total price is: " + price)
```

Comment: consider using a `while` loop.`while user == "yes"` for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
price, num = 0, 0
user = 'yes'
while user == 'yes':
    price += int(input(f"Please enter the price of product {num}:"))
    user = input ("Do you want to continue (yes/no):")
 print("Your total price is: " + price)
```

maybe the code above will serve ur purpose.

for the variable 'num', I add it because I assume u may want to record the order of the products